# How to count duplicate items in XMLList and assign them into an ArrayCollection?

Tags: apache-flex

I've following XMLList ,

`<party/>
<party/>
<party/>
<party>A</party>
<party>B</party>
<party>C</party>
<party>A</party>
<party>B</party>
<party>C</party>
<party>D</party>
<party>E</party>
<party>D</party>
<party>A</party>
<party/>
<party>C</party>`

I would like eliminate blank node and to make an ArrayCollection like ( with count of individual party),

tArr = new ArrayCollection([ {Party:"A", Count:3},
                      {Party:"B", Count:2},
                      {Party:"C", Count:3},
                  {Party:"D", Count:2},
                  {Party:"E", Count:1},
                     ]);

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Solution :

http://www.linkedin.com/groupItem?view=&gid=65596&type=member&item=20332755

Answer (score 0):

This is untested and may not be the most efficient, but should work:

```
var partyDict:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
var parties:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

var xml:XML = <root><party/><party/><party/><party>A</party><party>B</party><party>C</party><party>A</party><party>B</party><party>C</party><party>D</party><party>E</party><party>D</party><party>A</party><party/><party>C</party></root>;

for each (var p:XML in xml.party) {
    var val:String = p.toString();
    if ((val != null) && StringUtil.trim(val).length > 0) {
        if (partyDict[val] != null) {
            partyDict[val] = (partyDict[val] as int) + 1; // may simply be able to do partyDict[val]++;
        } else {
            partyDict[val] = 1;
        }
    }
}

for (var key:Object in partyDict) {
    var o:Object = new Object();
    o.Party = key;
    o.Count = partyDict[key];
    parties.addItem(o);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the list of possible parties it's just:

```
var partiesObjs:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

var xml:XML = <root><party/><party/><party/><party>A</party><party>B</party><party>C</party><party>A</party><party>B</party><party>C</party><party>D</party><party>E</party><party>D</party><party>A</party><party/><party>C</party></root>;
var parties:Array = ["A","B","C","D"]

for each(var p:String in parties){
  var count:int = xml..party.(toString() == p).length()
  partiesObjs.addItem( {Party:p, Count:count} )
}
```